# Packaging Shared Libraries

Tags: linux, qt, packaging

I have cross-compiled a simple hello world application for Linux running on ARM platform. If I use static linking the application runs fine on the target.

However, when I use dynamic linking using the shared libraries, I understand that I need to put the dependent libraries on target (ex: `libc.so.6` and `libgcc_s.so.1`).
I have set the env.variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `:/usr/local/lib` where I have copied the `.so` files.

When I run the application on my target now I get

```
-sh: ./a.out: not found
```

... every single time. I would like to ask if I have done anything wrong, or is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You're likely missing the dynamic linker, often named ld-linux.so.2. But note that ld-linux.so.2 is what inspects `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  and it's path is hard coded in the binary, meaning you can't place that wherever you want, such as in  /usr/local/lib/.  Run `readelf   -p .interp   ./yourprogram` ,  or `objdump -s  -j .interp ./yourprogram` and see what it says.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked

Comment: Hello,


I have ported an application to ARM-LINUX platform which uses shared libraries. The application starts execution and fails to call a method and exits.

Since the application runs fine on x86, I assume the problem is at the target.
Since the application statrts execution I assume all shared libraries are present on the target. 

Do you have any suggestions how to solve/debug this ? 

Thanks in advance,

Praveen